# javascript validation for allow -1 and all positive numbers in text box

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate a text box to allow all positive numbers including -1 in it.

i tried this, which will work for allowing only positive numbers

```
  function allownumbers(e, txtBox) {
        var key;

        key = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
        if (e.charCode == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((key < 48 || key > 57) && (key != 46) && (key != 44)) {               
            return false;                
        }
        if (key == 46) {
            if ((txtBox.value).indexOf('.') != -1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (key == 44) {
            if ((txtBox.value).indexOf(',') != -1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

But how to allow  -1(only) with all positive numbers
Thanks in advance

Comment: `parseInt(txtBox.value, 10) >= -1` ???  If you don't want 0, also use `!== 0`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [text box validation to allow -1 to +100](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498113/text-box-validation-to-allow-1-to-100)

Comment: Elliot Bonneville - input should be numbers >=-1 to all positive numbers in text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of preventing keystrokes, why not validate and sanitize the input? Maybe something like this:

```
function allownumbers(e, txtBox) {
    var val = parseInt(txtBox.value);
    if(!val || val < -1) {
        val = 0; // invalid value, reset to zero
    }

    txtBox.value = val;
}
```